# What would be a sql query of " USA State" come first?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have MySQL table named employees with

```
 1. id 
 2. employee 
 3. state
```

I am not getting an idea how I can query the database where state with the name "New York" will come first and all other records will come normally. Here is what I have so far

```
$sql = "select * from employees order by";
```

Comment: Can you tell us a little more about the requirements? Why do you want the results in this order?

Comment: actually i want to display staff of new yark first in the list the then others.

Comment: you could make a new field like `order_id` and then in your query do `....ORDER BY order_id....` edit:nicNLD solution is better

Comment: If you are just creating this table, please consider changing it so state is its own table. Here's what I have 

`StateID  CountryID Name Abbreviation`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simplest option:

```
ORDER BY (state = 'New York') DESC, state
```

Because `(state = 'New York')` will return either 1 (true) or 0 (false), you can easily order the results so that New York (where `state = 'New York'` returns 1) is returned before the other states.

The other option was to use `CASE`:

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN state = 'New York' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, state
```

Comment: can you please write me complete $sql?  like
$sql = "select * from employees order by when state='New York'"; Please remember that i want to display all items but just New Your first in the list?

Comment: Yes I can but no I won't. Why don't you do it yourself? Writing the above comment has actually cost you more effort than simply pasting my piece of code at the end of the query you already have. If you want me to do the work for you, I'm available for hire ;)

Comment: @NicNLD - bizarrely, he almost typed out what he wanted you to type when he asked you to type it...

Answer (score 3):

```
select * from employees order by state="New York" desc;
```

This orders records by the state equalling New York, or not. I noticed you spelled it New Yark twice, so you may need to un-correct the above for it to work with your data. The "desc" causes the ordering to descend rather than ascend, putting the 'true' values first.

As JClaspill notes, records without state equalling "New York" will be ordered naturally, not by state. Adding `, state` to the `order by` statement would sort those other records by state alphabetically but keep "New York" records first.

Comment: This is a great approach. Just a note, that this will only place new york at the top. It won't order the things after it in any fashion. Add a ',state' after the desc to have it then order the rest of the results in order.

Comment: Nice one @JClaspill, have clarified. OP doesn't really make it clear what ordering the other records should have, but good to note.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Control Flow Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html) and [String Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html) to prepend "AAA" to "New York" and to nothing else.

Order by the resulting string.

Comment: I want to display all the records just "New york" will come first other records will come normally.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a condition to the order by that forces the relevant state higher up the rank:

```
mysql [sandbox]> create table t1 (id integer primary key, state varchar(20));
mysql [sandbox]> insert into t1 values(1,'Last State'), (2, 'First State');
mysql [sandbox]> select * from t1;
1   Last State
2   First State
mysql [sandbox]> select * from t1 order by state='Last State';
2   First State
1   Last State
```

This evaluates to "False, True" for the 2 rows, which sorts to bring the false condition to the top.

Answer (score 0):

$sql = "SELECT * FROM employees ORDER BY CASE WHEN state = \'New York\' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, state";